# Azure DataFactory: Get status Message from an api

Tags: azure-data-factory

How can I get the status message from an api, I am calling it from a web activity in azure datafactory but the answer it gives me is: error 2108 which corresponds to an error message from Azure and I need a response from 201 or 504 depending on the case.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you mean Http status Code? It seems not able to get Http status code in web activity.

Comment: That's right, I'm talking about Http status Code, so how can I get this status? I need it for the GET and PUT methods but I can't find how to get that status message

Answer (score 0):

we are not able to get the Http status code.
The infomation we can get from the web activity is as follows:
[image]
In my case, the first four properties are from my rest api response. You can define a customer code property in your web api and write to your json response. So you can get your customer code.